# Running Google BigQuery sample network analysis script, I get a syntax error: Was expecting: <EOF>

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to use [sample code](https://blog.gdeltproject.org/google-bigquery-gkg-2-0-sample-queries/)  for Google BigQuery.  The query is in legacy SQL.

I have this set in BigQuery query:

```sql
SELECT
  a.name,
  b.name,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (FLATTEN(
    SELECT
      GKGRECORDID,
      UNIQUE(REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(V2Persons,';'), r',.*', ")) 
name
FROM [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg] 
WHERE DATE>20150302000000 and DATE < 20150304000000 and V2Persons like 
'%Tsipras%'
,name)) a
JOIN EACH (
SELECT GKGRECORDID, UNIQUE(REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(V2Persons,';'), r',.*', ")) name
    FROM
      [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg]
    WHERE
      DATE>20150302000000
      AND DATE < 20150304000000
      AND V2Persons LIKE '%Tsipras%')) b
ON
  a.GKGRECORDID=b.GKGRECORDID
WHERE
  a.name<b.name
GROUP EACH BY
  1,
  2
ORDER BY
  3 DESC
LIMIT
  250
```

But it raises the error:

> Error: Encountered " "ON" "ON "" at line 11, column 1. Was expecting:

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: My question is how to fix this error.  :)

Comment: it is hard to fix total mess. where you got this? is this something you ended up by yourself - or got somewhere? you might rather explain what it is that you are trying to achieve here

Comment: I got the code here:  https://blog.gdeltproject.org/google-bigquery-gkg-2-0-sample-queries/

Comment: I am attempting to retrieve data from the GDELT that will generate an output file that contains pairs of names and frequency counts so that I can import to Gephi and produce a graph.

Comment: i see source of your issue - see details in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 1 to many `)` characters after the join. Specifically `'%Tsipras%')) b` should likely be `'%Tsipras%') b`.
Most errors where you see "Was expecting: " after because of mismatched opening and closing pairs with too many closings.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure 100% if this is exactly what you expected  - but at least from syntax prospective the fix is below

```
SELECT a.name, b.name, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM (FLATTEN(
SELECT GKGRECORDID, UNIQUE(REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(V2Persons,';'), r',.*', '')) 
name
FROM [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg] 
WHERE DATE>20150302000000 AND DATE < 20150304000000 AND V2Persons LIKE 
'%Tsipras%'
,name)) a
JOIN EACH (
SELECT GKGRECORDID, UNIQUE(REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(V2Persons,';'), r',.*', '')) 
name
FROM [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg] 
WHERE DATE>20150302000000 AND DATE < 20150304000000 AND V2Persons LIKE 
'%Tsipras%') b
ON a.GKGRECORDID=b.GKGRECORDID
WHERE a.name<b.name
GROUP EACH BY 1,2
ORDER BY 3 DESC
LIMIT 250
```

Fixes are in line 3, 10 and 14

In lines 3 and 10 - I replaced `"` with `''`
In line 14 - I removed extra `)`

I am not sure with line 14 - as it might be that openning `(` is actually missing